# Will local flights already booked with Alitalia's cancelled because of the bankruptcy ? ROMA - CATANIA?

Tags: event-based-effects, alitalia

Good day!!
Do any of you know if the local flights already booked with Alitalia in June 2017 will be cancelled or will be honored? for example, ROMA - CATANIA? will I still be able to get on this flight in June? Thanks!